# What does renewSession do in pac4j?

Tags: pac4j

I was wondering what the impact of `setRenewSession(false)`. I can see it used in `DefaultCallbackLogic` and it is mentioned in the [doc](https://www.pac4j.org/docs/session-store.html), but I cannot really understand what's the effect it has and in which use case I should set it.